# Is it possible to reach the uploaded file by an http request in Angular 9 from $_FILES?

Tags: php, angular, post, httprequest

I'm trying to upload a file to a php server through an http request in angular 9, but the server is not able to receive the uploaded file in $_FILES. The code which I wrote somewhat looks like:

html:

```
<input type="file"  (change)="detectFiles($event)" name="testFile" >
```

php:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    echo json_encode($_FILES['testFile']['name']);
?>
```

typescript:

```
detectFiles(event) {
   const file = event.target.files[0];
   this.httpClient.post<any>('http://localhost/test/uploadFile.php', file )
     .subscribe( (response) => { console.log('uploading is done: ' + response); },
                 (error) => { console.log('ERR during the uploading: ' + error); }  
   );
}
```

when I upload a file I'm having as result the following message: 
**ERR during the uploading: [object Object]**.
Is there any possibility to reach the uploaded file from $_FILES in the server side?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: send with FormData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

append your file into `Formdata` and send this

```
detectFiles(event) {
   var formData = new FormData();
   formData.append("file", event.target.files[0]);  
   this.httpClient.post<any>('http://localhost/test/uploadFile.php', formData)
     .subscribe( (response) => { console.log('uploading is done: ' + response); },
                 (error) => { console.log('ERR during the uploading: ' + error); }  
   );
}
```